# Replacing usage of 'xalan' library for regular expressions with java.util.regex

Tags: java, regex

I am using 'xalan' library (2.7.2) for regular expressions in my Java application.
I want to replace it with java.util.regex.
I understand that for regular expression engines there are something called a "flavor" (which can be one of the flavors shown in https://regex101.com for example)
From what I checked java.util.regex uses the "Java" flavor.

The regular expressions which are the input for the application are coming from an external source (clients), so I cannot know in advance what all possible REs can be (otherwise if all REs were internal in the application I would simply test all of them)

An example of parsing an IP address using xalan and java.util.regex: (In the application the regex, text and parenthesis are provided as input)

```
String regex = "ddress.*:\\s*(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)";
String text = "Windows IP Configuration\n" +
    "\n" +
    "\n" +
    "Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:\n" +
    "\n" +
    "   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :asfasf\n" +
    "   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : asfasf\n" +
    "   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : asfaf\n" +
    "   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.11\n" +
    "   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255\n" +
    "   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::\n" +
    "                                       \n" +
    "\n" +
    "Ethernet adapter Ethernet:\n" +
    "\n" +
    "   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : lan\n" +
    "   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : sdsdfs\n" +
    "   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : sdgsdg\n" +
    "   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : sdgsdg\n" +
    "   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : sdgsdgs\n" +
    "   ";
// Using xalan org.apache.regexp        
RE reCmd = new RE(regex);
String str=null;
if (reCmd.match(text))
{
    str = reCmd.getParen(1);
}
System.out.println(str);

// Using java.util.regex
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
if(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

For this example both implementations print 192.168.100.11

My questions are:

1. Is the xalan library (2.7.2) also using the 'Java' flavor? (I tried searching the web and code itself, but didn't find out).
2. Is it safe to replace xalan library (2.7.2) with java.util.regexp? i.e would all existing regular expressions that worked with xalan will also work with java.util.regex? (assuming of course I will replace the existing code with its java.util.regex equivalent)

**Another option** is to find a regular expression that will work only in the 'Java' flavor, but will fail on all others. Then I can use this RE on both old (xalan) and new (java.util.regex) implementations and if they behave the same I will know they are the same flavor. The problem is that I wasn't able to construct such RE.

So basically, to summarize I'm only worried about the flavor that might be a problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think 'flavors' could be a rather imprecisely defined concept. Perl tends to be the gold standard for regex (but even that varies over versions) but I'd say it would depend on how 'advanced' your existing REs were. I think you'd certainly need to test the more advanced ones

Comment: Thanks, good point (I will update also in the post). The regular expressions which are the input for the application are coming from an external source (clients), so I cannot know in advance what all possible REs can be (otherwise if all REs were internal in the application I would simply test all of them). So I worry that by replacing the flavor I might break exiting clients REs. When you say an 'advance' RE, can you give an example of an such RE that will work on 'Java' flavor, but will fail on any other flavor?

Comment: @mike Could you kindly give an idea of your use case and supply a kind of example? How are REs going to be coupled/related to Xalan/XSLT?

Comment: Added an example of parsing using xalan and java.util.regex to the post.

Comment: With regexp "Some text here(.*)\n([^]*)", above code sample works with xalan, but doesn't work with java.util.regexp. It seems like it works only in **EMCAScript (Java Script)**, but not in Java.

Is someone familiar with a Java replacement for xalan that supports EMCAScript (Java Script) flavor?